# How to create communication between python(not web) and angularjs

Tags: python, angularjs

I have an angularjs and a python project. The angularjs for the frontend and the python part is for the trainings made for face recognition. I wanted to know if there is a way that my angular can communicate with python and if it can, how to use the functionalities of python project in the angular.

Answer (score 0):

Just build the simplest possible server using the [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) framework! It's so easy to learn and there are lots of tutorials over the internet. If it's as simple as you said, it should be enough with one or two routes, just to `POST` and image and obtain the results.

From the `Angular` side you'll have to call your server (API) using the [Http Client](https://angular.io/guide/http) already provided in the angular core.

Answer (score 0):

Create an  API in python console application 
call http get put etc  from angular .